# Parse JSON using map() in JS

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I need to get all "Need" values from such a JSON:

```
var body = {"payload":[
   {
      "analitic": {
         "id": 9448,
         "name": "Group"
      },
      "key": 27,
      "data": [
         {
            "id": 35368,
            "name": "sku",
            "value": "1",
            "valueId": "Need_1"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "analitic": {
         "id": 9448,
         "name": "Group"
      },
      "key": 110,
      "data": [
         {
            "id": 35368,
            "name": "sku",
            "value": "1",
            "valueId": "Need_2"
         }
            ]
         }      
]
   }
```

I think to use map () for this. Am I on the right track? And how do I get just these values? (I minified the json, there are many other fields in the original that I don't need)

**UPD:
The solution after studying codecademy turned out like this:**

```
body.payload.map(function(i) {return i.data.filter(function(j) 
{return j.id == 35368}).map(function(k) 
{return k.valueId})}).join(",")

// result: "Need_1, Need_2"
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Anything that starts with `= {` in JS is not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your "data" key is an array with only 1 element, you can extract the need values in an array as following:

```js
var body = {"payload":[
   {
      "analitic": {
         "id": 9448,
         "name": "Group"
      },
      "key": 27,
      "data": [
         {
            "id": 35368,
            "name": "sku",
            "value": "1",
            "valueId": "Need_1"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "analitic": {
         "id": 9448,
         "name": "Group"
      },
      "key": 110,
      "data": [
         {
            "id": 35368,
            "name": "sku",
            "value": "1",
            "valueId": "Need_2"
         }
            ]
         }      
]
   }
   
 var res = body['payload'].map((arr)=>arr['data'][0]['valueId']);
 console.log(res);
```

Comment: "there are many other fields in the original that I don't need" - so while this works with the data in the question, it might not work with the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

The solution after studying codecademy turned out like this:

```
body.payload.map(function(i) {return i.data.filter(function(j) 
{return j.id == 35368}).map(function(k) 
{return k.valueId})}).join(",")

// result: "Need_1, Need_2"
```